# Nice way to say "exclude"

Tags: word-choice, politeness

I have a bunch of components I have included into a new project. I drew a pretty picture showing all of them, color coding the ones I selected, then showing the conglomeration. I went to write up the key to explain the colors, but didn't know how to kindly say "this one did not get picked" in a word or two. `Excluded` was a close as I could come, but it sounds mean.

Is there a nice way to say "this component did not get selected for inclusion into the new project" in a word or two?

Comment: Exclude isn't a pejorative. Why are you documenting finalist components (instead of selected components)?

Comment: How about "didn't qualify"?  Or "hasn't been selected"?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Good question. I'm combining four software baselines into one, and need to show everyone what parts made the cut and what didn't. Exclusion here can hurt people's feelings so I wanted to be gentle about it.

Comment: @Luis Right now I have "Not included" in the key. Still seems harsh to me.

Comment: How about: *Targeted for phase 2*.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch "Targeted for phase two" would be nice, but it's not accurate. We have four baselines that do essentially the same thing. I am condensing them to one, after which we will abandon the old baselines. There is no phase two.

Comment: Then you're going to be calling someone's baby ugly. Expect hurt feelings.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch has a good point here. There is no way to sugar coat it when you're picking winners and losers.  The best method I can think of (assuming this is a "PowerPoint" type presentation) is to first display all the baselines considered, and then in a second slide, display "Chosen Baselines".

Comment: If you are condensing four similar things into one then 3 out of 4 components will get rejected (or some can possibly get merged). If you sugar coat the rejection, then you open up the door for people to try to change your mind, and stall the project. Just rip off the bandaid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to come up with a wording for a label to explain the color code that means "this component did not get selected for inclusion into the new project," and you want it to sound as upbeat as possible, you might try something like this:

> Carefully considered but ultimately not included.

The wording indicates that you gave the nominated item serious thought and even suggests that under other circumstances you might have selected it—but it also acknowledges the inescapable fact that you chose not to include it.

Beyond the label you choose for the color code, you can soften the blow to the disappointed champions of the excluded components by emphasizing somewhere—in your presentation of the illustration, say, or in a cover note—that you were overwhelmed by the numerous excellent options your colleagues suggested, that you appreciate the thought and effort that went into the nominations, that you regret that you couldn't include them all in the project, etc., etc.

I'm afraid that's about the best you can do when forced to identify the ugly babies (as Elliott Frisch says in a comment above) as well as the winners in an infant beauty contest.

Answer (score 1):

> Rejected

is okay. Or there is

> eliminate
>   rule out
>   factor out

but I think that "ruled out" is the best of them, as it isn't as negative.

Answer (score 1):

You can say *"...of all the candidates, here are the ones **selected** to be included..."*  That way, you're focusing on the chosen ones, not dwelling on the rejected ones.

Answer (score 0):

For your consideration:

> [Remediate](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/remediate) - to act
>   between parties to effect an agreement, compromise, reconciliation,
>   etc.

Given that you are in fact reconciling four software baselines, saying those particular requirements have been "remediated" might be nice way to say that they are no longer in scope.  You can intimate that they are being removed because they either already represented on one of the other baselines, or that the functionality would cause a conflict with one of other baselines.

"In reconciling the four baselines, the following components have been remediated."